# Counter Strike Source map rotation based on time of day

Tags: counter-strike-source, server-administration

I am admin and owner of a Counter Strike Source server. We have a decent number of people on and off but we are still sort of new and have a bit of a fracture in what the people who play want and what will draw more traffic.

We largely only play DE and CS maps but some people want more stock maps and think a rotation of mostly if not exclusively stock maps. Some people think we should just run the server with the stock maps we like and a whole host of other custom maps and people who don't like it can deal with it.

What I want to know is are there any server plugins you know that allow map rotation to be changed based on the time of day or number of players currently on the server.

So far [I've only found this plugin](http://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?p=599464), but it hasn't been supported since 2008 it seems and based on the comments it would appear it works at times but has some issues with some of the variables.

Comment: This is the kind of thing where a SourceMod plugin would be excellent.  If I wasn't so rusty, I could probably write it myself.  If you're willing to invest a small amount of money, or you ask reaaaal nice, you might find someone on the AM forums who would be willing to write you something.

Answer (score -1):

I can't find any, but requesting a plugin from some forums is always an option. One forum that I found is pretty good. **[Click Here](http://forums.alliedmods.net/)** to go to the website.